# c# how to count the amount of json values

Tags: c#, json

So, I am trying to count the amount of values in JSON using c#. The Json is:

```
{
  "Someid": 657442,
  "roles": [
    {
      "id": 3892751,
      "name": "Guest",
      "rank": 0,
      "memberCount": 0
    },
    {
      "id": 3892750,
      "name": "Fanz!<3",
      "rank": 1,
      "memberCount": 0
    },
    {
      "id": 3892749,
      "name": "Lead-Singer",
      "rank": 254,
      "memberCount": 0
    },
    {
      "id": 3892748,
      "name": "Drums",
      "rank": 255,
      "memberCount": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to count the amount "roles". The JSON is just in a string variable. Help?

Comment: Deserialize it into an array, then get `Length`?

Comment: Deserialize it to the appropriate data structure, and read `obj.Roles.Length`?

Comment: I'd suggest starting with https://app.quicktype.io?share=IEs9emLGOZgseqkyggdt .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either use like this:

```
var token = JToken.Parse(input);
var roles= token.Value<JArray>("roles");
var count = roles.Count;
```

Or you can also use JsonPath:

```
var token = JToken.Parse(input);
var count = token.SelectTokens("$.roles[*]").Count();
```

But ideally, you should be serilizing into an object and then using the properties to get the Count:

```
public class Role
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int rank { get; set; }
    public int memberCount { get; set; }
}

public class MyObject
{
    public int Someid { get; set; }
    public List<Role> roles { get; set; }
}

var item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(input);
var count = item.roles.Count;
```

Comment: I get the following error: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: With which example? And which line?